# Bayesian networks for text analysis in R

Tags: r, bayesian, text-analysis, bnlearn

I have one page story (i.e. text data), I need to use Bayesian network on that story and analyse the same. Could someone tell me whether it is possible in **R**? If yes, that how to proceed?

The objective of the analysis is - Extract Action Descriptions from
Narrative Text.
                                                                                                                                                        The data considered for analysis -

> Krishna’s Dharam-shasthra to Arjuna:
>
> The Gita is the conversation between Krishna and Arjuna leading up to the battle.
>   Krishna emphasised on two terms: Karma and Dharma. He told Arjun that this was a righteous war; a war of Dharma. Dharma is the way of righteousness or a set of rules and laws laid down. The Kauravas were on the side of Adharma and had broken rules and laws and hence Arjun would have to do his Karma to uphold Dharma.
>   Arjuna doesn't want to fight. He doesn't understand why he has to shed his family's blood for a kingdom that he doesn't even necessarily want. In his eyes, killing his evil and killing his family is the greatest sin of all. He casts down his weapons and tells Krishna he will not fight. Krishna, then, begins the systematic process of explaining why it is Arjuna's dharmic duty to fight and how he must fight in order to restore his karma.
>
> Krishna first explains the samsaric cycle of birth and death. He says there is no true death of the soul simply a sloughing of the body at the end of each round of birth and death. The purpose of this cycle is to allow a person to work off their karma, accumulated through lifetimes of action. If a person completes action selflessly, in service to God, then they can work off their karma, eventually leading to a dissolution of the soul, the achievement of enlightenment and vijnana, and an end to the samsaric cycle. If they act selfishly, then they keep accumulating debt, putting them further and further into karmic debt.

```
                                                                            What I want is - post tagger to separate verbs, nouns etc. and then create a meaningful network using that.
```

The steps that should be followed in pre-processing are:

1. syntactic processing (post tagger)
2. SRL algorithm (semantic role labelling of characters of the story)
3. conference resolution

Using all of the above I need to create a knowledge database and create a Bayesian network.

This is what I have tried so far to get post tagger:

```
txt <- c("As the years went by, they remained isolated in their city. Their numbers increased by freeing women from slavery.
Doom would come to the world in the form of Ares the god of war and the Son of Zeus. Ares was unhappy with the gods as he wanted to prove just how foul his father’s creation was. Hence, he decided to corrupt the mortal men created by Zeus. Fearing his wrath upon the world Zeus decided to create the God killer in order to stop Ares. He then commanded Hippolyta to mould a baby from the sand and clay of the island. Then the five goddesses went back into the Underworld, drawing out the last soul that remained in the Well and giving it incredible powers. The soul was merged with the clay and became flesh. Hippolyta had her daughter and named her Diana, Princess of the Amazons, the first child born on Paradise Island.   
Each of the six members of the  Greek Pantheon granted Diana a gift: Demeter, great strength; Athena, wisdom and courage; Artemis, a hunter's heart and a communion with animals; Aphrodite, beauty and a loving heart; Hestia, sisterhood with fire; Hermes, speed and the power of flight. Diana was also gifted with a sword, the Lasso of truth and the bracelets of penance as weapons to defeat Ares. 
The time arrived when Diana, protector of the Amazons and mankind was sent to the Man's World to defeat Ares and rid the mortal men off his corruption. Diana believed that only love could truly rid the world of his influence. Diana was successfully able to complete the task she was sent out by defeating Ares and saving the world. 
")

writeLines(txt, tf <- tempfile())

library(stringi)
library(cleanNLP)
cnlp_init_tokenizers()
anno <- cnlp_annotate(tf)
names(anno)
get_token(anno)

cnlp_init_spacy()
anno <- cnlp_annotate(tf)
get_token(anno)

cnlp_init_corenlp()
```

Comment: Please include example of your data, wanted output (bayesian analysis is too broad) and what you have tried, otherwise your question will be closed as too broad. Here's [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: The objective of the analysis is - Extract Action Descriptions from
Narrative Text.                                                                                                                                                          The data considered for analysis -

Comment: Question is too broad and very hard to understand

Comment: I have edited the question and explained what I want ,along with the text data

Comment: I have edited the question to show you what I have tried so far.Please check

Comment: this might better be posted on the https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What a pagerank ...